# @Appstorage get stuck/won't update between views

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, appstorage

I'm making my very first app in Swift with XCode 13.4.1, which is a Pomodoro. In this app, user can have up to 4 tasks

But I'm facing to a problem and I can't find a solution and it sounds like a bug :/

The var are set like this (that's not optimal I know) :

```
   @AppStorage(wrappedValue: false, "task1") var task1
   @AppStorage(wrappedValue: "Nom", "task1Name") var task1Name
   @AppStorage(wrappedValue: 0, "task1TimeLeft") var task1TimeLeft
   @AppStorage(wrappedValue: 0, "task1Duration") var task1Duration
   // Same for the 3 other task
```

When the user create a task, a pop-up view is show and user set a name, a duration and the category. When this is done, user return to the view where he can manage all the tasks.

When the user set the duration of a task with the var "task_Duration" (_ = 1,2,3 or 4), the task manager shows the duration with a progress bar and a label, the main view only do one thing : withdraw one seconds each seconds to the var.

I've 3 views linked to 3 classes : a main view with timer, a view to manage task and a last one to create one.
To share the variable between the views, I use @AppStorage like this :

```
   class ViewController: UIViewController { 
   /// The main view which shows the timer

   @AppStorage(wrappedValue: false, "task1") var task1
   @AppStorage(wrappedValue: "Nom", "task1Name") var task1Name
   @AppStorage(wrappedValue: 0, "task1TimeLeft") var task1TimeLeft
   @AppStorage(wrappedValue: 0, "task1Duration") var task1Duration
   
   // I skip all the unnecessary code

   func updateTimer(){ // a timer withdraw 1 to time var every seconds
       if time <1{
          // timer end, if timeLeft == 0 the task is deleted (task_ = false)
       } else{
          task_TimeLeft -= 1
       }
   }

  }

  class TaskManager: UIViewController {
   @AppStorage(wrappedValue: false, "task1") var task1
   @AppStorage(wrappedValue: "Nom", "task1Name") var task1Name
   @AppStorage(wrappedValue: 0, "task1TimeLeft") var task1TimeLeft
   @AppStorage(wrappedValue: 0, "task1Duration") var task1Duration
   ... (and the other)
   
   // this view show all the informations about the task, nothing interesting for the problem 
      except that the "taskTimeLeft" is ok before the main view withdraw one
  }

  class TaskEditor: UIViewController {
    @AppStorage(wrappedValue: false, "task1") var task1
    @AppStorage(wrappedValue: "Nom", "task1Name") var task1Name
    @AppStorage(wrappedValue: 0, "task1TimeLeft") var task1TimeLeft
    @AppStorage(wrappedValue: 0, "task1Duration") var task1Duration
    ... (and the other)

    @IBAction func closeButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
       
       if task1IsEditing == true // a var defined when user touch the task in the manager {
           task1Name = String(format: "\(taskTextField.text ?? "Sans nom")")
           task1 = true
           task1Duration = Int(taskTimeSlider.value) * 60
           task1TimeLeft = task1Duration
           
           performSegue(withIdentifier: "managerFromTask", sender: self)
   }
  }
```

**So, here is the problem** : when the user start the timer with a task, everything is okay, the taskTimeLeft is reduced. But, if I define a new taskTimeLeft with the others views and if I start the timer, the main view is stuck and withdraw 1 to the the last taskTimeLeft

For example, I set a pomodoro with a 25 min duration, I start the timer but stop it 10 min later -> taskTimeLeft = 15min. I delete the task and create another one with a 40min duration. Then I start the timer, stop it 5 min later aand -> taskTimeLeft = 10 min ??

By the way, I also have the exact same problem when a button set a var named "taskSelected" to 0, the other views can't change that 0, I need to restart the app to change the 0 the the value that I set.

I tried outdated methods like UserDefaults.standard.actualize() but it doesn't work and depreciated.

Please can you help me, I'm stuck on this problem since many days :'(

Comment: I am pretty sure @AppStorage is for SwiftUI only.

Comment: I imported SwiftUI but not noticed it here but am I wrong using appstorage like this so ?

Comment: Just importing SwiftUI will not be enough, you need to actually use it instead of UIKit. So better use UserDefaults instead

Comment: Ok I will try this solution thanks, but do you know why this work one time and not twice ? and why other var work nicely ? (I'm just asking for learning sorry)

Comment: `AppStroage` conforms to `DynamicProperty` and `DynamicProperty` gets its updated values from `SwiftUI.View.body`, if there is no `body` you don't get any updated values. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamicproperty A combination of actions can make it get reinitialized and make it seem like it is updating but that is a fluke, not intentional.

Comment: Oh okay I see ! Thanks a lot for this explaination 